# The next Page is scrolled down in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have two webpages written in asp.net, vb.net is code behind. When I click on next button in one page the second page should appear.  The second page is huge one, when I click on the next button, the page is coming, but its focus is bottom, in order to go top, I need to use the scrolling, what I want is to make the focus top.

Comment: It should load with the focus at the top. does your link from page 1 to page 2 contain an anchor (#) ?

Comment: No. It is kind of report page. I am using response.redirect("page2.aspx", false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9731/How-to-scroll-an-ASP-NET-control-into-view-after-p) so that your page will be scrolled to a specific control on your page.

The code should be put in your CodeBehind. 
Just choose some control which is at the top of your page and it should do the work..

I should note that having your page scroll to the bottom is an unusual behavior and shouldn't be happening by default. You should probably check why it's happening in the first place.

**Update:**

Updated the code since the method used there is obsolete...

```
private void FocusControlOnPageLoad(string ClientID)
{

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "FocusOnControl",

            @"<script> 

              function ScrollView()

              {
                 var el = document.getElementById('" + ClientID + @"')
                 if (el != null)
                 {        
                    el.scrollIntoView();
                    el.focus();
                 }
              }

              window.onload = ScrollView;

              </script>");

}
```

Usage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FocusControlOnPageLoad(yourcontrol.ClientID); 
}
```

**Equivalent VB.Net:** (Thanks to @Mahyar)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    FocusControlOnPageLoad(yourcontrol.ClientID)
End Sub
Private Sub FocusControlOnPageLoad(ByVal ClientID As String)
    Dim script As String = _
        "<script>" + _
            "function ScrollView()" + _
            "{" + _
                "var el = document.getElementById('" + ClientID + "')" + _
                "if (el != null)" + _
                "{" + _
                "el.scrollIntoView();" + _
                "el.focus();" + _
                "}" + _
            "}" + _
            "window.onload = ScrollView;" + _
        "</script>"
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "FocusOnControl", script)
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah..it is not converting properly.

Comment: PeterJennings, @Mahyar has added the VB.Net equivalent in my answer above

Comment: can 'yourcontrol' be my control called label and its id is lable1

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> <Scripts> <asp:ScriptReference Path="./Scripts/focus-handler.js" /> </Scripts> </asp:ScriptManager>    THIS IS WHAT I AM USING IN ASPX

Comment: Peter, add to your question the aspx code of the begining of the problematic page so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you have aspx, then just add this script to the end of page before Body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
</script>
```

Comment: No difference. Still same situation.  I am poping the page will lot of controls programatically in code-behind page. The number of controls that display in the second page vary in logic.

Comment: added Converted code in VB.net to Blachshma answer (edited).. waits for approval

Comment: my control is lable1, there were no syntax errors, but the behavious is samee. The page is scrolled down.

Comment: i tried with label control and panel controls ( these controls are on the top of the page). But focus is still at the bottom.

Comment: looks like the focus-handler.js you are referencing, keeps the focus at the bottom, am I right?

Comment: yes. I commented the scriptmanager section. Now it is working without adding any code.

Comment: ok, you can add `window.scrollTo(0,0);` to the end of **focus-handler.js** file, and I guess it will be ok. if not then there is an EventHandler in this script which executes after Body or Html tags.  I tried to reproduce your case by adding a ScriptManager and referencing a similar focus-handler.js , but as I don't know what focus-handler.js contains, I was unsuccessful :)

Comment: Hi Mahyar, see focus-handler.js in my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146334/asp-net-next-page-is-focus-is-moving-to-the-bottom-always

Comment: did you try to add window.scrollTo which I mentioned in the previus comment to the end of focus-handler.js file and see what happens?